# Giving input x and n just need to find the exponential value

Tags: python, compiler-errors

With constraints being (0 <= x <= 8, 0 <= n <= 9)
Output should be x^n (i.e. x raised to the power n)
I am getting error in here . Cant understand why

```
n_input = input()
given_input = n_input.split(" ")
x = int(given_input[0])
n = int(given_input[1])
if (0<=x<=8 and 0<=n<=9):
    output = x**n
    print(output)
else:
    print("Values of x and n exceeding constraints")
```

Comment: Mention what's the error.

Comment: Please put the error text into the question. Thanks.

Comment: Your code worked on my machine.

Comment: This will only work with python3

Comment: When I am trying to submit the code with custom input the test cases are failing there. It is just showing error . I dont know why